# iOS UIButton click doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uibutton

I have an issue with iOS `UIButton` click handling programmatically.

I have a `UIButton`:

```
- (UIButton *)compareButton
{
    if (!_compareButton)
    {
        NSString *title = TITLE;

        NSDictionary *attributes = TITLE_ATTRIBUTES;

        NSAttributedString *attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title attributes:attributes];

        _compareButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 20.0f, 100.0f, 44.0f)];

        _compareButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

        [_compareButton setAttributedTitle:attributedTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_compareButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonCompareClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }

    return _compareButton;
}
```

`UIButton` clicks should be handled by method

```
- (void)buttonCompareClicked:(UIButton *)sender
```

Also, I have a `UIView`:

```
- (UIView *)header
{
    if (!_header)
    {
        UIView *header = [[UIView alloc] init];

        header.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        [self.view addSubview:header];

        _header = header;
    }

    return _header;
}
```

My button is a subview of a view:

```
[self.header addSubview:self.compareButton];
```

All user interactions are enabled:

```
self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
self.header.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
self.compareButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Despite of this, button click doesn't trigger method call.

Where might be a problem with this?

Comment: Did you set the IBAction connection?

Comment: Do you use storyboards or any XIB file that contains the button?

Comment: I don't see where you're setting the header's frame, or adding constraints to lay it out with auto layout. It may have zero width and height. Try setting its `backgroundColor` property so you can see if it has a valid size.

Comment: Look at my getter! There is a `backgroundColor ` set. The frame of header is correct. At the moment of subview adding, header frame equals to zero, but it should't change anything.

Comment: I am not using XIB or a storyboard...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with `self.header`. You need to set frame to it.

```
self.header.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 80);
```

After this that your button should start registering touch.

**WHY?**

Good Question.

As you `self.header`'s layer have property `maskToBounds` which by default set to no, so any view that you add inside `header` view will be visible. But since your `header` view have no area to tap on, that make any `subviews` untappable. That is why your button is not registering the touch.

Comment: Thank you a lot for great answer with explanation!

Comment: But if the header view doesn't have an area unless he sets it, how are the subviews visible?

Answer (score 2):

1-You need to set the frame of your header view:

```
UIView *header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 20.0f, 100.0f, 44.0f)];
```

2-So in this case, set the frame of your button relatively to the header view:

```
_compareButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 44.0f)];
```

3-Don't forget to set the compareButton property to strong:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *compareButton;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with this.

```
[self.header addSubview:[self compareButton]];
```

Hope this may help you.....

Comment: Why this should help?

Comment: self.compareButton actually calls [self compareButton] , so this won't change anything

Comment: And it doesn't change anything

Comment: i think , you should try after changing ControlEvents of this UIButton.

Comment: Change this UIControlEventTouchUpInside and Try.

Comment: This surely won't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
    //Better to Use Below lines
    _comparebutton=[UIButton buttonwithtype:UIButtontyperoundrect];
    [_comparebutton setframe:CGRectMake(0.0f, 20.0f, 100.0f, 44.0f)];
    //instead of
    //_compareButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 20.0f, 100.0f, 44.0f)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify your code as below

```
- (UIView *)header
{
    if (!_header)
    {
        UIView *header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 44.0f)];

        header.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        [header addSubView:[self compareButton]];//add this line of code

        [self.view addSubview:header];

        _header = header;
    }

    return _header;
}
```

//AND modify

```
- (UIButton *)compareButton
{
    if (!_compareButton)
    {
        NSString *title = TITLE;

        NSDictionary *attributes = TITLE_ATTRIBUTES;

        NSAttributedString *attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title attributes:attributes];

      _compareButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];//modified
      _compareButton.frame=CGRectMake(0.0f, 20.0f, 100.0f, 44.0f);//modified

        _compareButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

        [_compareButton setAttributedTitle:attributedTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_compareButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonCompareClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }

    return _compareButton;
}

-(IBAction)buttonCompareClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"@@@@@@@@@Button Compare Called@@@@@@@");
}
```

Hope it fixes the issue....!